# Code to @ discord bot and have it reply to you the prefix's and blah blah

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
#these are the modules needed
#Note: I don't want an if statement EX if "@Bot" == True
await.message.channel.send('words')
```

The reason Why I don't want this is because I tried it and when I command the Prefixhelp command the "word" is always in the second line of every command the bot can do, which is annoying so can anyone very quickly give me the code to have it not do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way of getting a reply when some user tags your bot would be using a decorator in the bot instance:

```
from discord.ext import commands 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"))
```

But if you only want people to be able to simply send a message tagging your bot and it returns the prefix, you can simply check with the function `mentioned_in` to see if the bot is being mentioned in the message.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("The prefix is '!'")
```